Benjamin Libet Free Will Experiment

I'm unable to understand this GIF of Benjamin Libet's free will experiment.
Please look at the bottom left of the diagram and you'll see the numbers 1 followed by 2 and then by 3.
What I think is happening

The part of your brain controlling your finger fires.

This stage represents you making a conscious decision to move your finger.

Your finger moves.


The yellow circle around the zig-zag wires represents a light bulb detector.
Is my reading of the GIF correct?
For more details visit Benjamin Libet

IMO your interpretation is correct.
The explanation of the above scetch of Libet's experiment says:

0 repose
1 (−500 ms) EEG measures Readiness potential
2 (−200 ms)
Person notes the position of the dot when decides
3 (  0 ms) Act

The relevant question concerning free will asks: What does happen at time 2?

Does the person decide consciously at time 2, or does the person
only register, what has been determined at time 1 by her
unconscious mental processes?

Added: Please see also the interesting paper from the first link of @mudskipper. The linked paper from 2008 reports an improvement of the Libet experiment. Its result is a refined localisation and time determination of the unconscious origin of movements which were intended as "free" decisions by the test person.

+1 For interesting follow-up experiments by Heinze and Haynes (predictions with delay of > 10 sec), see "Unconscious determinants of free decisions in the human brain" (Nature, 2008), http://behavioralhealth2000.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Unconscious-determinants-of-free-decisions-in-the-human-brain.pdf
For a good , short critical review see: https://www.templeton.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/FreeWill-JTF-Final.pdf
I would add that a relevant question is also: What does it mean that "the person decides" -- why would the process from 1. up to 2. not be considered part of that?

@mudskipper Generally, to take a "decision" means a conscious mental process. Of course the whole Libet process operates within a person. But naming the whole process a decision forces one to split a decision into a conscious and a non-conscious part. Do you prefer to do so?  - Thanks for pointing to the paper of Soon, Brass, Heinze and Haynes. 10 sec seems quite a lot!

As to the role of consciousness - I think there are other views too (see also the Templeton Foundation report that I linked to).  What's interesting are also the experiments of Schleger (also referenced in that report) with hypnotized subjects ; Schleger found no relation between RP and any conscious awareness of intention (as probably could be expected with hypnotized subjects :)

Thank you for the confirmation. I didn't notice the 0 position. This is evidence that our decisions may not be consciously made. In essence if free were a possibility the sequence would've been 0, 2, (1), 3. Correct?
